# phusion passenger nginx module installation error on ubuntu server (12.04.2) 64 bit due to g++ --> internal compiler error

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, g++, passenger

**sudo passenger-install-nginx-module**

```
--------------------------------------------

Where do you want to install Nginx to?

Please specify a prefix directory [/opt/nginx]:

--------------------------------------------

Compiling Passenger support files...
# /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/local/bin/rake nginx:clean nginx RELEASE=yes
rm -rf ext/common/libboost_oxt.a ext/common/libboost_oxt
rm -rf ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libpassenger_common
rm -f agents/PassengerWatchdog agents/PassengerLoggingAgent
rm -rf agents/nginx/PassengerHelperAgent
mkdir -p ext/common/libboost_oxt
g++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.o -c ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp
In file included from ext/boost/src/pthread/thread.cpp:27:0,
                 from ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp:6:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function âvoid {anonymous}::to_time(int, boost::xtime&)â:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:22:9: warning: variable âresâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function âvoid {anonymous}::to_timespec_duration(const boost::xtime&, timespec&)â:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:59:9: warning: variable âresâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function âvoid {anonymous}::to_duration(boost::xtime, int&)â:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:90:9: warning: variable âresâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function âvoid {anonymous}::to_microduration(boost::xtime, int&)â:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:112:9: warning: variable âresâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
mkdir -p ext/common/libboost_oxt
rm -rf ext/common/libboost_oxt.a
ar cru ext/common/libboost_oxt.a ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.o
ranlib ext/common/libboost_oxt.a
mkdir -p ext/common/libpassenger_common
g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.o -c ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (4): [g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev  -D_REE...]
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/build/cplusplus_support.rb:31:in `compile_cxx'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/build/common_library.rb:126:in `define_common_library_task'
Tasks: TOP => nginx => agents/nginx/PassengerHelperAgent => ext/common/libpassenger_common.a => ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**OS**

Ubuntu server 64 bit
os version - 12.04.2 (latest update)

**ruby -v**

ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

**rails -v**

rails version - 2.3.16

**passenger --version**

Phusion Passenger version 3.0.19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increasing RAM size from 256 MB to **1 GB solved the issue**, initially i was running an cloud instance with 256 MB of RAM, This makes g++ don't have enough memory to compile.

Comment: I had a similar problem on my VPS, so added a swapfile based on this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: I tried to install passenger on Amazon EC2 t2.micro (1GB memory) but the compilation always failed.
Then I switched to t2.small (2GB memory) and it worked!